# How to hide the time slot in kendoui Scheduler

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I was able to hide the whole day and reduce the number of hours shown to just one row. But I'm not able to hide this row.

[image]

The scheduler is vertical grouping scheduler, with room number on right and date on top. The code for this is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Angular Scheduler</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>


<style scoped>

    .k-scheduler-toolbar,.k-scheduler-footer
    {
        /* make them invisible */
        display: none;
     
        /* prevent height and paddings from influencing the size calculations */
        height: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="example" ng-app="KendoDemos">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <div ng-cloak kendo-scheduler k-options="schedulerOptions">
        <div k-event-template class="movie-template">
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div> 
   <script>
     angular.module("KendoDemos", [ "kendo.directives" ]).
controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){

    $scope.schedulerOptions = {
            eventHeight: 40,
            majorTick: 1440,//set major tick to full day and leave the default startTime/endTime
            minorTickCount: 1,//show only one minor tick
            majorTimeHeaderTemplate: "",
            timeSlot:false,
            ShowTimeRuler :false,
        editable: {
          template: $("#customEditorTemplate").html()
        },
        date: new Date("2013/6/13"),
        startTime: new Date("2013/6/13 07:00 AM"),
        height: 600,
        views: [
        
            "day",
            { 
            type: "week", 
            selected: true ,
            dateHeaderTemplate: "<span class='k-link k-nav-day'>#=kendo.toString(date, ' dd/M')#</span>"
            },
            "workWeek",
            "month",
        ],
        timezone: "Etc/UTC",
        dataSource: {
            batch: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/tasks",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                },
                update: {
                    url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/tasks/update",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                },
                create: {
                    url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/tasks/create",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/tasks/destroy",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                },
                parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                    }
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "taskId",
                    fields: {
                        taskId: { from: "TaskID", type: "number" },
                        title: { from: "Title", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
                        start: { type: "date", from: "Start" },
                        end: { type: "date", from: "End" },
                        startTimezone: { from: "StartTimezone" },
                        endTimezone: { from: "EndTimezone" },
                        description: { from: "Description" },
                        recurrenceId: { from: "RecurrenceID" },
                        recurrenceRule: { from: "RecurrenceRule" },
                        recurrenceException: { from: "RecurrenceException" },
                        ownerId: { from: "OwnerID", defaultValue: 1 },
                        isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" }
                    }
                }
            },
            filter: {
                logic: "or",
                filters: [
                    { field: "ownerId", operator: "eq", value: 1 },
                    { field: "ownerId", operator: "eq", value: 2 }
                ]
            }
        },
        dataBound: function(e) {
                //hide the times row from the date/time header:
                var view = this.view();
                view.datesHeader.find("tr:last").prev().hide();
                view.timesHeader.find("tr:last").prev().hide();
                
                
                //Required: remove only last table in dataBound when grouped
                
                var tables = $(".k-scheduler-times .k-scheduler-table");
                tables = tables.last();

                var rows = tables.find("tr");

                rows.each(function() {
                  $(this).children("th:last").hide();
                });
              
            },
        //vertical grouping of rooms
        group: {
            resources: ["Rooms"],
            orientation: "vertical"
        },
       //Rooms details
        resources: [
            {
                field: "roomId",
                name: "Rooms",
                dataSource: [
                    { text: "Room 101", value: 1, color: "#6eb3fa" },
                    { text: "Room 201", value: 2, color: "#f58a8a" },
                    { text: "Room 301", value: 3, color: "#2c0eca" },
                    { text: "Room 401", value: 4, color: "#ed8312" },
                    { text: "Room 501", value: 5, color: "#2cdeca" },
                    { text: "Room 601", value: 6, color: "#c3ff42" },
                    { text: "Room 701", value: 7, color: "#3aeeca" },
                    { text: "Room 801", value: 8, color: "#21d187" },
                    { text: "Room 901", value: 9, color: "#5371a0" },
                ],
                title: "Room"
            },
            {
                field: "ownerId",
                title: "Owner",
                dataSource: [
                    { text: "Alex", value: 1, color: "#f8a398" },
                    { text: "Bob", value: 2, color: "#51a0ed" },
                    { text: "Charlie", value: 3, color: "#56ca85" }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
  })
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here i have tried to delete the rows using both jquery and CSS but nothing seems to work

`$('td.k-nonwork-hour').remove();` this just removes the color of that particular row that i want to remove

I need something like this. This was done by me in jQuery.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to remove one of the slots is to set [allDaySlot](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler/configuration/alldayslot): false as for example it is done in this [dojo page](http://dojo.telerik.com/@zdravkov/eRIPeHEJ).